# How can I save wallet boarding pass from a link in iOS?

Tags: ios, wallet

I don't know anything about how the wallet works. I've read it's documentation. And I know that I need to generate some pkpass file on server.

What I want to do is to generate some pkpass file for user and bring the link to this file inside the app.

Can I add this file to wallet from external link. e.g User clicks on a link and this link leads to pkpass file. Would the system recognise this file as a wallet and propose the user to save it in his wallet?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/YourFirst.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH2-SW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not do that.  You need to have an app to show and add passes to your wallet. You can get content of the url using following

```
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your url string will come here"]];
```

Once you get your file data as `NSData` you can create `PKPass` from it. `PKPass` initialiser takes `NSData` as parameter and generates `PKPass`. And then you can use `PKAddPassesViewController` to show the pass or passes which you have downloaded.

Comment: you mean that this files needs to be stored inside my app? what about Wallet App? I thought that all passes are stored to separate wallet app

Comment: ok. i think i got it. I need to get wallet data then present it in PKPASsViewcontroller, it already has add to Wallet button